# Wildfly Block URL Pattern

Tags: security, jboss, wildfly, http-status-code-403

Is there any config for wildfly application server to block customized URL pattern, or how can I block Bypassing 403 endpoints request for security purpose.

for example: my URL is https://xxxxxxxx.com/service

how can i block the URL like: https://xxxxxxxx.com/service/static/..;/

Comment: Do you mean access from the outside or access from a client within the container?

Comment: THanks For your reply, i mean  access from outside.

Comment: Are you ok with code to do this? I don't think that there is anything built in.   And is this a servlet application, a HTML application, or a JAX-RS application (or some combination of them)?